# Subview of UITableView does not have same height as tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with constraints in storyboard that take up the entire superview. In my viewDidLoad(..) for the associated VC, I load a .xib (UIView), and then add it as a subview of the tableView.

```
let emptyHomescreenView = EmptyHomescreenView() //The nib is loaded earlier.
self.tableView.addSubview(emptyHomescreenView)
```

No matter what, I see that emptyHomeScreenView has a longer height than it should. It is placed properly in the tableView, but it is simply the height that is the problem. I have tried setting the height manually to be the same as the tableView, but no change. I have also tried setting the tableView's contentInset.bottom to a new value, but that also doesn't change (weirdly top does work).

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -self.navigationController!.toolbar.frame.size.height, right: 0)
//Above line doesn't work, setting a value for top does modify the emptyHomescreenView however.
```

I then tried

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom
```

which reduced the height of emptyHomescreenView, but it still wasn't quite aligning with the bottom toolbar of the navController.

Anyone know why this is the case? I am using autolayout for the xib.

Edit [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8hh3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your contentInset is double-bumping your content.  Set all of the values of your contentInset to 0.  Your TableView should already be flush with the tool bar, and the content view of the tableView is measured relative to the tableview's bounds, not the global view space.

Comment: I have contentInset values set to 0, unfortunately contentView is not a property I can access from tableView.